# How to get the html form value from razor page?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a form having Name and isVisible as checkbox. data is loaded from api. now i want to edit the visibility status of the names (section names). i have checkbox for the visibility which is okay but what about names how to get the id of the name against the checkbox selected.

html code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 bg-white p-5 rounded-8">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right mt-3">
        <button type="submit" id="btnSaveSectionVisibility" value="Save" class="btn btn-custom">Save</button>
        <a class="btn btn-custom" id="lnksectionVisibileCancel">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    <form class="row row-margin-zero needs-validation" asp-controller="Group" asp-action="AddVisibility" method="Post" id="frmAddSectionVisibility" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
        <table class="research" border="1" style="background-color:azure;text-transform:full-width">
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var groups in Model)
                {

                    <tr class="accordion" style="cursor:pointer">
                        <td colspan=@Model.Count.ToString() ;>@groups.Name</td>
                    </tr>
                }

                <tr>

                    <td><strong>Section</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Visibility</strong></td>

                </tr>

                @foreach (var groups in Model)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < groups.SectionRespnses.Count; i++)
                    {
            <tr>
                <td>@groups.SectionRespnses[i].Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="chk" name="name4" id="groups.SectionRespnses[i].id"/>@groups.SectionRespnses[i].Name</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="name4" /></td>
            </tr>
                    }

                 }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>

</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".research tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
        $(".research tr:first-child").show();

        $(".research tr.accordion").click(function () {
            $(this).nextAll("tr").fadeToggle(500);
        }).eq(0).trigger('click');
    });
    $("#btnSaveSectionVisibility").click(function () {
        var form = $("#frmAddSectionVisibility");
        alert(form);
        //if (form.valid()) {

        var url = form.attr("action");
       
        var lists = [];
        $('.chk:checked').each(function () {
            var data = [
                $(this).val()
            ]
            lists.push(data);
        });


        // var data = form.serialize()

        var sectionCreateRequest = {
            GroupId: $("#hdnGroupId").val(),
            SectionIds: lists
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            url: url,
            data: sectionCreateRequest
        }).done(function (response) {
            if (response.toLowerCase().indexOf("success") >= 0) {
                toastr.success(response);

                /* GetAllGroups();*/
                //LoadRolesTable()
            }
            else
                toastr.info(response);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to get the id of the name against the checkbox selected

Do you mean you want to get the textbox’s id attribute when you checked the checkbox?

To get the textbox’s id attribute, we could use the checkbox click event, after checking the checkbox, we could find its parent element (the `<tr>` element), then we can find the textbox based on its type (since there only have one textbox in the selected row), and get the id attribute.

1.Add two `<div>` at the end of the form. They are used to display the selected id value.

```
    <tr>                
       <td>@groups.SectionRespnses[i].Name</td>
       <td><input type="text" class="chk" name="name4" id="@groups.SectionRespnses[i].id"/>@groups.SectionRespnses[i].Name</td>                                       
       <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="name4" /></td>                   
    </tr> 



 <div id="selectedLabel" style="display:none"></div>
 <span id="selected"></span>
```

[Note]: When you bind the id attribute, the code should be `id="@groups.SectionRespnses[i].id"`

2.js Demo as below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
    //get all 
        var $all = $('.chk');
    //get the area to write the results 
    var $selectedListing = $('#selected');
    //get the label
    var $selectedLabel = $('#selectedLabel');

    //when you click a checkbox, do the logic
    $all.on('click', function () {
        //set the content of the results
        $selectedListing.html(
            //only return those that are checked
            $all.filter(':checked').map(function (index, checkbox) {
                //return a id of the name against the checkbox selected
                var id = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='text']").attr("id");
                return id;
            }).get() //get  a id of the name against the checkbox selected
        );

    //hide the label if no checkboxes are selected
    if ($selectedListing.text().trim().length) {
        $selectedLabel.show();
        } else {
        $selectedLabel.hide();
        }
   });
});
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**For Example Creating a Simple HTML Form:**

In Form.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Customer Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form method="post" >
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Add Customer</legend>
          <div>
            <label for="CompanyName">Company Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="CompanyName" value="" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="ContactName">Contact Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="ContactName" value="" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="Employees">Employee Count:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Employees" value="" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Reading User Input from the Form:**

To process the form, you add code that reads the submitted field values and does something with them. This procedure shows you how to read the fields and display the user input on the page.

At the top of the Form.cshtml file, enter the following code:

```
@{
    if (IsPost) {
        string companyname = Request.Form["companyname"];
        string contactname = Request.Form["contactname"];
        int employeecount = Request.Form["employees"].AsInt();

        <text>
          You entered: <br />
          Company Name: @companyname <br />
          Contact Name: @contactname <br />
          Employee Count: @employeecount <br />
        </text>
    }
}
```

Comment: right but how about getting the checkbox with key mapped value. we need to deal with some js code to get the value behind the checkbox right?